# NextAuth "signIn" callback usage?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Trying to implement the `callbacks.signIn()` function in my NextAuth configuration and am not sure what I'm missing to make it redirect.

Here's my `callbacks` object in `[...nextauth].ts`...

```js
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user }) {
            const allowedEmails = process.env.ALLOWED_EMAILS;
            if (allowedEmails.includes(user.email)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('redirect!')
                return '/unauthorized';
            }
        },
    },
```

According to the docs, returning a string is an option, but all I see is the 'redirect!' log when the condition isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

It is said "Or you can return a URL to redirect to".
Page for error (return false) should be sufficient and useful for many other issues (unaothoresed.tsx is then 404.tsx for example)